# How do I filter email in cpanel using 'match regex' for the following?

Tags: regex, email, filter, cpanel

I'm looking to filter the following emails in cpanel via regex.

Buy New Furniture <**spamword**234@ryrtyhd.net>

Win Jackpot <**spamword**5346@dfsdfs.com>

<**spamword**678@fdgsaj.com>

So basically i want to filter an email if it matches the following in the email header.

```
From: any name here, present or absent <spamword(any numbers from 0-9999)@anydomain.extension
```

Any ideas? Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
.*\<spamword[0-9]{1,6}\@.+\>$
```